# Get data of other than selected class in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a `jquery datatable` in which I select records by having checkbox selected. For ex: If I have 5 records in a datatable and I select 2 records from that. I get **2** records by below code.

```
var tableToViewSummary1 = $('#viewSummary2');
tableToViewSummary1.empty();

var table1 = $(dtCertifyEFO).DataTable();
var data1 = table1.rows('.selected').data().toArray();

alert(data1.length);
```

So now what I want is, I want all the records other than which are not selected. It means i want **3** records

Please suggest how to get this

Below is the sample fiddle of the same

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8nct19x/)

Comment: I can't see any checkbox in fiddle. Also, `dtCertifyEFO` is not defined.

Comment: there are checkboxes & `dtCertifyEFO` is defined already globally. its class is `select-checkbox`

Comment: `table1.rows(':not(.selected)').data()...`

Comment: Can you include jquery code as well in fiddle?

Comment: There's no need for any code/checkboxes/html/fiddle etc.  OP has `.rows('.selected')` and wants the inverse of this, so it's `.rows(':not(.selected)')`

Comment: @freedomn-m: thanks, it's exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using datatables .rows, you can provide a selector, specifically this is a "jquery selector" so can use any jquery options

https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector

As you already have `.rows('.selected')`, the inverse is:

```
var data1 = table1.rows(':not(.selected)').data().toArray();
```

Comment: hi, can we also get the only data whose status is `'CMM Approved'` from my updated fiddle. Please respond.@

Comment: From your fiddle, it's not clear what you mean,  Your best bet is to ask a new question and provide all the details.